# getiing null values while converting the string column to date format

Tags: pyspark

I am getting null values of date
here is my code. I have created a dataframe and pass date as a string format

```
data=[('anmol','',27000,'21/01/1998'),('anubhav',25,39000,'20/06/1997'),('ravi',25,8900,''),              ('','',70000,''),('','','','')]`
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField
    schema=StructType([StructField('Name', StringType()),
            StructField('Age', StringType()),
            StructField('Income', StringType()),
            StructField('Date', StringType())])
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example")\
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()
    df1=spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
```

here i am converting the string date format into a date format

df3=df1.select(to_date(df1.Date,'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('dt'))

Comment: provide the source format in `to_date` instead of the target format

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the format as in the data -

```
df3=df1.select(to_date(df1.Date,'dd/MM/yyyy').alias('dt'))
```